# Multi-source BFS with traveling graph problem with expanding cells

Tags: algorithm, search, language-agnostic, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

You are given a M x M grid (7 <= M <= 1000) where every cell can either be occupied or is inaccessible. You are also given the locations of several starting points where you can start moving from.

You can start at any starting location. In one unit of time, you can travel to any of the adjacent cells (the one above you, the one to the right of you, the one to the left of you, or the one below you). After every T units of time, the number of cells you occupy expands in all 4 directions. When you travel to different cells in the future, all the cells you occupy move in a coordinated mass in the same direction.

For example, if you expanded after every 1 unit of time, and you're moving in an empty grid to the right, this is how the cells you occupy would expand, where O = square you occupy:

```
.......  .......  .......
.......  .......  ..O....
.......  .O.....  .OOO...
O......  OOO....  OOOOO..
.......  .O.....  .OOO...
.......  .......  ..O....
.......  .......  .......
```

If after traveling to an adjacent cell or expanding, one of your cells move to an inaccessible square, you stop moving or expanding. You will always eventually stop moving or expanding because the border of the grid is all inaccessible.

The question is to determine you many different squares you can occupy.

Example:
The grid is 10 x 10, and you expand after every 2 units of time. The starting locations are marked with an S, the inaccessible cells are marked with Xs, and the empty squares you can occupy are marked with “.”:

```
XXXXXXXXXX
X.X......X
X.X......X
XS.......X
X.X......X
X.X......X
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
```

The number of locations that could be reached is 28. They are marked on the grid with Os:

```
XXXXXXXXXX
XOX.OOO..X
XOXOOOOO.X
XOOOOOOOOX
XOXOOOOO.X
XOX.OOO..X
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
```

My solution:

Firstly, since the grid only ranges to a maximum size of 1000 x 1000 units, you could store a boolean M x M matrix which stores if a particular square could have been reached or not. At the end of the solution, you would iterate over this matrix, and count the number of squares that could be occupied.

One idea I had to solve this problem was to use a multi-source BFS. You would start by adding all starting locations to the queue. The state could be [M][M][K], where the first two states would correspond to the location that is occupied within the grid, and K corresponds to the number of units of time left until it must expand. You could process each unit occupied individually in this manner. Every time you process a state, you would add four states back to the queue: [M - 1][M][K - 1], [M + 1][M][K - 1], [M][M - 1][K - 1], and [M][M + 1][K - 1]. If K = 0 at any point in time, you would add the states [M - 1][M][K], [M + 1][M][K], [M][M - 1][K], and [M][M + 1][K] back into the queue. You would eventually reach all cells that could be reached in this manner.

The problem with this approach lies in the rule that if any cell within the mass of cells moves into a border or an inaccessible square, you cannot continue moving or expanding. With the solution I outlined above, there is no way of knowing if the current cell can continue to move or expand.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I didn't find it easy to understand the pattern of expansion. You say `you can travel to any of the adjacent cells (the one above you, the one to the right of you, the one to the left of you, or the one below you)` but the examples which you gave follow something different.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Yes, you can travel to any of the adjacent cells as I described earlier. When you expand, you expand into the diamond shape as illustrated. The example I gave with the expanding diamond was of you the mass of cells moving steadily one unit to the right, and expanding after every movement. Let me know if you need more clarification.